# Sonoff switch with override wall switch

Tags: switch, home-automation, wifi

I have a fan, a light and two sonoff basic devices to control them. As sonoff can only work with internet, I thought it would be a good idea to be able to fully override the controls with separate switch just in case.

[image: Diagram for connecting sonoff]
Basically, I want to use three separate switch.

- if only **S2** is on, the state of the devices will depend on sonoff
- if **S1** is on the light is always on
- if **S3** is on the fan is always on
- if all three switches are off the devices are always off

I am aware that the button on sonoff can be used to override. However, I will be concealing the devices as they look a bit ugly while exposed.

I want to know if this setup is safe and will work without burning anything up.

Comment: Related: Questions about Sonoff switches come up fairly regularly on [IOT](https://iot.stackexchange.com/) (Internet Of Things) Stack Exchange.  Also, depending on where you are in the world, Sonoff may or may not be “listed” or approved for use.

Comment: "*override the controls with separate switch just in case*" Just in case of what ?

Comment: *"sonoff can only work with internet"* -- Just in case the internet goes down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would hesitate to give a definitive answer to this because it's obvious in your circuit that when S1 is ON and S2 is OFF then you are connecting mains to the output of Sonoff 1 with no connection to it's input.

However, I have checked my own Sonoff (Basic R2) and the input line is switched to the output by a mechanical relay with no other connection to the output so I can see no reason why this wouldn't be perfectly safe. Worth checking yours is the same though as other versions may be different.